# Magento Import products Internal Server Error

Tags: php-7, server-setup, import-products, product-import

I just clicked on Check data for imported file I have inserted

It keeps on loading there is in infinite Please wait

and sometimes shows

```
500


Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at you@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

My value for phpinfo is attached

[image: Php info]

Answer (score 1):

This might also be related to some kind of an infinite loop into your code or internal error in your code.

You might want also to check on your `var/log/system.log` to see if there isn't any error that could explain that.

If you have no error, then in your special case, the most appropriate would be to rise the max execution time before your import with the method `set_time_limit(XXXXXX);`

Comment: 2020-09-29 07:02:05] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []                                      system log says

Comment: should i increase time_limit in .user.ini

Comment: where should this be set??

Comment: I recently got the same issue with Amqp, in my case I just disabled that module. But may be you are using it.

I think you can just increese in the controller import php file. If it is the default one, you need to override with a preference.

Comment: I can not disable the module, I am using it

Comment: At least You might want to disable it just for testing purpose and see if without the module your import is running well. We also had an import and while running it we saw like 20 call to this amqp during one product import...not sure how it works but it looks quite suspicious.

Comment: The issue is not solved even after disabling this module